# Incomplete AWR snapshots

Tags: oracle, report, awr

I have a question regarding Oracle AWR reports. At the end of the AWR Report there is a Warning:

### Warnings

The optimal memory target for the instance could not be determined because of
incomplete AWR snapshots.

The complete end of the report states:

### Additional Information

### Warnings

The optimal memory target for the instance could not be determined because of
incomplete AWR snapshots.

### Miscellaneous Information

Wait class "Application" was not consuming significant database time.

Wait class "Commit" was not consuming significant database time.

Wait class "Concurrency" was not consuming significant database time.

Wait class "Configuration" was not consuming significant database time.

CPU was not a bottleneck for the instance.

Wait class "Network" was not consuming significant database time.

Session connect and disconnect calls were not consuming significant database
time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFccE.png)

My question is: How should I interpret this Warnings? What could be done to fix this Warning?
Thank you.